# Part of string conversion into integer - C++

Tags: c++, string, integer, static-cast

I'm wondering if I can convert part of my string into an integer using `static_cast`?
I know that something like `atoi()` exists, but should I really use it in order to converse only the first character of my string into integer?

```
int w;
string my_str;
getline(cin, my_str);
w = static_cast<int>(my_str[0]) - 48;
```

Is something like this correct? Or should I do this in another way?

Comment: The fact that @Marvin has edited that question and `48` is so close to `42` amuses me a lot :)

Comment: `my_str[0]` will return a `char`, so casting it to an int is redundant.

Answer (score 5):

As long you are sure that `my_str[0]` contains a digit character, it's fine.

You should avoid magic numbers like `48` though, better write `w = my_str[0] - '0';`

The number `48` is the ASCII code numeric representation of `'0'`. There are other [character code systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) (like EBCDIC codes) and the c or c++ languages don't have an explicit notion of these, and the numerical representations can completely differ.

That said using `'0'` will be portable for many character code systems not just ASCII codes.

Comment: But why - '0' ?
When I did it using char[] instead of string I wrote '- 48' and it was correct.

Comment: @Monika It's the ASCII char representation of 48. Chars themselves are handled as numeric values. You wouldn't even need the `static_cast<int>`.

Comment: So if -'0' stands for - 48 , can't I use this second option?

Comment: @Monika IMHO `'0'` is clearer, but you can use `48` of course.

Comment: The C++ standard does not guarantee `'0'` to be 48. So `'0'` is not just nicer, it's also the only correct way.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I explicitly mentioned _ASCII_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: But I think your comment does not clearly indicate that ASCII is optional for C++.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Clarified in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no any need to use static_cast because in any case the integer promotion is applied to the expression `my_str[0]` of type `char`. So these two expressions

```
static_cast<int>(my_str[0]) - 48;
```

and

```
my_str[0] - 48;
```

are equivalent.

This is correct provided that you want to convert only one character of the string. Otherwise you should use standard function `stoi`.

Also instead of the magic number 48 it is much better to use character literal `'0'`

```
my_str[0] - '0';
```

because it is more readable and clear and does not depend on used coding system. For example in EBCDIC the code of zero is `0xF0`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are better off using `'0'` rather than `48`.

While it is true that an ASCII representation (or compatible representations) are used most often in practice, there are standardised character sets with `'0'` not numerically equal to `48`.

There is also a readability argument.   It is harder for a mere mortal to understand code using magic numbers like `48`.   Which makes it easier to understand what `x - '0'` is doing over `x - 48`.

Answer (score 0):

Your cast returns the ascii code of your first character. And you don't actually need the cast. `my_str[0] - '0'` does the job too.

As long as it is something between '0' and '9' this works as you want it. But you have to check the result. Because if that char is something out of the boundary you'll get a negative or a number over 9 as result

Comment: I don't know what my_str[0] contains because the programm's user can write there whatever they want. But after this and after conversion I'm checking if it is the right value ( I need value between '1' and '5') 

 `int wybor; 
do{ 
wybor_opcji.clear(); 
getline(cin, wybor_opcji); 
wybor = static_cast<int>(wybor_opcji[0]) - 48; 
} while((wybor_opcji[0] < '1') || (wybor_opcji[0] > '5') ); `

Is it correct checking inside while() or should I wirte '1' and '5' wihtout '' ?

Comment: That looks good then. Since you're converting the char to integer, why don't you use the `wybor` value in your while condition? like this: `while((wybor < 1) || (wybor > 5) );`

Answer (score 0):

Computers can only understand numbers, that is why character on your keyboard <sup>(and other)</sup> are represented using an encoding system<sup>1</sup>, where each character is assigned with a unique number.

Strings are sequences of characters, where as we said each character is represented by a number. In the case where character representation<sup>(like ASCII)</sup> involves  lining the digits `'0'` through `9` sequentially starting from `'0'`.

If  you have a character that is a digit, subtracting `'0'` *"converts"* it to it's digit value, because the expression in your case:

```
w = static_cast<int>(my_str[0]) - 48;
```

performs a subtraction between the numbers<sup>`int`</sup> representing the character values. Where the decimal value:`48` uniquely represents the character `'0'`<sup>2</sup>.

The `static_cast<int>` is an overkill as the whole right hand side is consisted of integers

Note: subtracting `'0'` is an old trick for conversions used by people that really knew what computers were all about, unlike us.

---

<sup>1. An example of encoding standard is [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).</sup>

<sup>2. `'0'` in ASCII = `48` // in Decimal.</sup>

P.S.: The question would have been even better if the number `42` was the ASCII code numeric representation of `'0'`, then each and every answer would have been very interesting to read.